# iOS check if secondary app slide over

Tags: ios, objective-c, multitasking

**Question:**
Is it possible to **check if another app** is opened as a ***secondary 'slide over'*** ?

**The issue:**
What I've found so far is that if my app are using the Camera. If it goes to multitasking or a secondary app is opened as 'slide over' the camera stops working.
For multitasking and slide over for the app itself you can enable full screen and the problem is solved. However you can't block that another app is opened as 'slide over' when your app is running.

Because this will block the Camera I would like to show an alert or message when the user opens a secondary app as 'slide over'.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this doesn't come too late!I will also admit I don't know the obj-c because I'm working in Xamarin but I had the same issue as you.

This sample code from Apple should help a lot though! :)
[Objective-C/AVCam/AVCamCameraViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Objective_C_AVCam_AVCamCameraViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Objective_C_AVCam_AVCamCameraViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_7)

From what I can interpret, you can add an observer on "AVCaptureSessionWasInterruptedNotification" and then look for the enum "AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonVideoDeviceNotAvailableWithMultipleForegroundApps" in the method associated with the observer.

Hope it helps!